# How to copy value of one data column into another data column in the same data table C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to copy `itemarray[4]` of datatable to `itemarray[6]` of that datatable. I used this code and I didn’t see any changes:

```
foreach (DataRow dr_row in dt_table.Rows)
{
    foreach (var field_value in dr_row.ItemArray)
    {
        object cell_data = field_value;
        if (dr_row.ItemArray[6].ToString() == "")
        {
            dr_row.ItemArray[6] = dr_row.ItemArray[4];
        }
        original_data += cell_data.ToString();
    }
    original_data += Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all never do this:

```
dr_row.ItemArray[6].ToString() == ""
```

Change it to this:

```
dr_row.ItemArray[6].ToString() == String.Empty
```

or:

```
 String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr_row.ItemArray[6].ToString())
```

However, that is just good practice. Now, to the problem that you are facing.

What the `Itemarray` does is, it creates a new array from the row, so that if you change the array, you do not change the row.

Do this:

```
dr_row[6] = dr_row[4];
```

Should work.

Comment: Why should you you never do == "" ?

Comment: Well the main reason is readabilty, but you can argue about that. the second reason is that when you use a "" or a " " its a String object for in the assembly, its true that if u use "" in evry part of your code it will still be the same object, but whay create a new object if there is a static one inside the String object?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 foreach (DataRow dr_row in dt_table.Rows)
  {
     dr_row[6] = dr_row[4];
  }
```

and use  `System.Text.StringBuilder` to append data.

```
 System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.Append(value1);
```